# Uso de variables globales en Pyton

Tags: python, variables

Queria saber si es mala o buena practica hacer uso de las variables globales?

por ejemplo este caso pero tambien quiero saber a nivel general

```
print('Calculadora de propinas! ')

cantidad_personas = None 
def ask_info():
    global monto_cuenta, porcentaje_propina
    monto_cuenta = float(input('Ingrese monto de la cuenta:      '))
    porcentaje_propina = float(input('Ingrese porcentaje de la propina:    '))
ask_info()

def calculo_monto_propina():
    global monto_propina
    monto_propina = (monto_cuenta * porcentaje_propina)/ 100
    print(f'El monto de la propina es: ', monto_propina)

calculo_monto_propina()

def total_pago():
    total_pago = monto_cuenta + monto_propina
```

si no es buena practica, cual seria la solucion?

Comment: La función debe **retornar** valores, no modificar variables globales. Alguien que ve una llamada a la función no se va a dar cuenta que esta tiene efectos laterales.

Comment: no entendi @CandidMoe

Comment: Es una pregunta muy interesante. Sin embargo, al estar basada en opiniones, no encaja con el formato del sitio, por lo que terminará cerrada. ¿Por que no vas al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) y lo preguntas allí? Tienes suficiente reputación para hacerlo.

Comment: Podrías retornar una tupla o una lista que retorne ambos datos, o hacer una función por cada una, y si recuerdo bien, antes de usar variables globales es mejor usar variables de entorno